# Why does wien's law only apply to blackbodies?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetic-radiation, temperature, thermal-radiation

thinking about it the sun is just made of atoms ,

if it absorbs or not it's different ? i don't exactly know how to word it;

just why only things that absorbs all radiations are valid in wien's law

Answer (score 1):

Objects that are not black bodies when they get light reflect and emit part of that light. A black body only emits radiation due to its molecules accelerating due to its temperature. When you have a real object and you measure its radiation you will be measuring the radiation due to its temperature (Wien's Law) plus the radiation of absorption-emission and reflection. So, Wien's law won't coincide with the measurements in real (not black) bodies.

Comment: It might still be applicable for simple grey bodies.

Comment: Yes, but applying some constant to the equation.

Comment: Not sure, I think the peak of the simple grey body coincides with the black body.

Comment: Yes, but the constant will affect other equations such as Stephan-Boltzsman's law. Sorry for not mentioning it.

Comment: i don't understand still,

Comment: @user49791 try to rephrase your question, what do you not understand?

Comment: @Mauricio what bothers me is which temperature of the sun to plug in , the core temp or the surface.if we think of the sun as just few atoms undergoing nuclear reaction & emitting light what is meant by ''the sun is a blackbody   that absorbs radiation (light)".

Comment: The problem you have may be that you think a black body is only an ideal absorber, but it is also an ideal emitter that emits all wavelengths. Usual objects don't emit all wavelengths so wien's law may not be applicable.

Comment: Apart from that the T to plug in in the case of the Sun would be the surface  one.

Comment: imagine we think of the sun , simplify it as just few atoms having nuclear reactions, & emmiting light , how to apply wiens's law here , & can thoses atoms be considered as a blackbody ,why would they be a blackbody ,

Comment: All the radiation of nucleus is absorbed by the core and becomes heat (temperature) the emission of light in the sun is because the atoms of the surface are hot. The nucleus doesn't radiate, it warms up the whole star.

Comment: to measure accurately you need a  substance that absorbs all radiations before emiting it , no reflections. Is it because if it reflects the experimental data is gonna be affected by the reflected light